# make div disable in html

Tags: html, css

I have a div like this:

```
<div class="load-more-home col-xs-12 btn" disabled="true">No more posts available </div>
```

I want to make it not clickable. So I added disable="true" but it doesn't work.

**I want to make it in HTML without javascript.**

I want to know if exists any attribute in HTML that makes a div unclickable because `disabled` isn't working.
Please help.

Edit:

this class `load-more-home` is called in a javascript function that generates posts, actually,  the difference between buttons is only the inner text.
When there are no more posts the text is replaced with "No more posts..". But by default I need to put there a not clickable div(div that acts like a button). I hope I explained it

Comment: div is not clickable at all.. unless you have used some javascript to make it happen.. `disabled` is not a valid attribute on div.. its for only inputs,buttons and links.. So first you need to say how is the div able to be clicked in the first place.. Then you might get help on how to stop it

Comment: Why you want to *disable* it? `disabled="true"` does not work, because div is not input and this attribute only applicable for inputs

Comment: All I see are I wants. Tell us what you've tried and you've done

Comment: You would probably need to create an overlapping element.

Comment: @AndrewL *I added disable="true" but it doesn't work* he did add what he tried.

Comment: HTML for links, buttons, and inputs allows you to set "disabled" as an attribute (e.g., <button disabled>Text</button>), but it's not an attribute that a div can have. Divs aren't clickable by default so have you set some Javascript to make the div clickable?

Comment: What wrong with `pointer-events: none` provided below?

Comment: you should use `button` rather than `div` and you can set `disabled` attribute on it.

Answer (score 13):

You can emulate it using css:

```css
.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<div class="disabled">
  <button>some clickable content</button>
</div>
```

Comment: or `div[disabled]` if you want to use a disabled attribute

Answer (score 11):

`disabled` isn't a valid property for `div`.
You can use this css statment to disable click events:

```
pointer-events:none;
```

Comment: This statment works correctly on click events like buttons, check it.

Comment: And check my JSFiddle... You can select the text and copy it. It's not disabled then...

Comment: I check it at the first time, and this statment don't have this finality, if you want to disable text selection, you need to use css statment `user-select: none;`

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<div class="load-more-home col-xs-12 btn" disabled="true">No more posts available </div>

.load-more-home{
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS to disable pointer events

```
#my-div {
pointer-events:none;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Only HTML, tricky but works:

```
<fieldset disabled='true'>Solution Name</fieldset>
```

Answer (score -1):

add attribute

```
style="cursor:none;"
```

Or like this

```
.notClick {
  cursor:none;
}
<div class="load-more-home notClick col-xs-12 btn">No more posts available </div>
```

Comment: It will only hide cursor but it will be clicked.